# Typo3 Error Warning htmlspecialchars()

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have a lot (like a lot) of warnings which are all the same in the Administration Log :

[image]

It's about htmlspecialchar() in a cached file.
I don't know what to do, we receive almost 50 000 logs like these every days.

I use Typo3 8.7.7 with PHP 7.2.5 and MySQL 5.5.60

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've a fluid-template where the viewhelper [f:format.htmlentities](https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation/TYPO3CMS-Guide-Extbase/blob/latest/Documentation/Fluid/ViewHelper/Format/Htmlentities.rst) is called.
At least in one of those templates you assign an array-variable instead of a string-variable to that viewhelper, that throws the error.